# Extending linq (where to place code)

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I came across [an article](http://craigcav.wordpress.com/2009/09/21/linq-each-iterator-with-exposed-index/) that describes how to create a .Each() for LINQ, a la jQuery.  I stuck the code in one of my controllers but when I try to call it, Intellisense doesn't see it... I also read an article from [4guysFromRolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020140103/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/070710-1.aspx) that describes how to create LINQ extensions but they don't talk about having to place the code in any special place...

what's the magic here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extension methods should be defined inside of a non-nested, non-generic static class: [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

Comment: in an MVC app, is there a preferred location to place this code?  it doesn't seem to fit under any of the /Models, /Controllers or /Views

Comment: @ekkis - ideally it should go to a separate project (assemlby), that has all the utility classes that are not dependent on your website.

Answer (score 3):

[Extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) belong into separate static class.

From linked article:

> The following example shows an extension method defined for the System.String class. Note that it is defined inside a non-nested, non-generic static class:

You should also add `using` to namespace of this class.

Answer (score 1):

You can place it anywhere but it would be wise to move it to a separate Tools folder+ns or even to an assembly.

A basic idea: create a `public static class MyLinqExtensions` in an `\MyExtensions` folder.

Replace 'My' with something Project specific.